# How to ignore specific column's values which have count more than 1 in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help creating a query which ignores a specific column's values which are present more than once in the table. In the below table, I want to ignore all the values of Column1 where count is greater than 1 (so ignore Apple and Cucumber)

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Bees |
| Apple | Fruits |
| Apple | Cheese |
| Banana | Pie |
| Carrot | Tea |
| Tomato | Pie |
| Cucumber | Meat |
| Cucumber | Toast |

**should give me**

| Row 1 | Row 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | Pie |
| Carrot | Tea |
| Tomato | Pie |

Answer (score 1):

You can use an analytic count, partitioned by column1; and use a CTE or subquery to filter out the rows where the count is not 1:

```
select column1, column2
from (
  select column1, column2, count(*) over (partition by column1) as cnt
  from your_table
)
where cnt = 1
```

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | Pie |
| Carrot | Tea |
| Tomato | Pie |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/51IzpOrU)